# No me permite insertar en la base de datos en mi servidor marcando este error General error: 1785 Statement violates GTID consistency

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

En el código de mi archivo de guardado al intentar insertar me marca un error:

> General error: 1785 Statement violates GTID consistency: Updates to
>   non-transactional tables can only be done in either autocommitted
>   statements or single-statement transactions, and never in the same
>   statement as updates to transactional tables.

He verificado los datos que envío para la inserción y se envían correctamente pero no me permite insertar y ya funcionaba pero de la nada  dejo de funcionar.
Aquí dejo el código que tengo:

```
try{
  $conexion->beginTransaction();

  $sql="INSERT INTO `colaboradores`(`fecha_ingreso`, `nombre`, `apellido_p`, `apellido_m`, `nombre_completo`, `fecha_nac`, `curp`, `rfc`, `grado_estudios`,`profesion`, `domicilio`, `no_ext`, `no_int`, `colonia`, `cp`, `estado`, `poblacion`, `tel1`, `tel2`,`tel3`, `correo`, `puesto`, `tipo`, `tipo_usu`, `nombre_usuario`, `contrasena`, `premisas`, `id_empresa`, `id_sucursal_p`, `nss`, `cuenta_bancaria`, `institucion_bancaria`,`image`) VALUES (:fecha_ingreso,:nombre,:apellido_p,:apellido_m,:nombre_completo,:fecha_nacimiento,:curp,:rfc,:grado_estudios,:profesion,:domicilio,:no_ext,:no_int,:colonia,:cp,:estado,:poblacion,:tel_1,:tel_2,:tel_3,:correo,:puesto,:tipo,:tipo_usu,:usuario,:contrasena,:premisas,:id_empresa,:sucursal,:nss,:cuenta,:i_bancaria,:imagen)";

  $stmt=$conexion->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bindParam(':fecha_ingreso',$fecha,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':nombre',$nombre,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':apellido_p',$apellido_p,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':apellido_m',$apellido_m,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':nombre_completo',$nombre_completo,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':fecha_nacimiento',$fecha_nc,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':curp',$curp,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':rfc',$rfc,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':grado_estudios',$grado_estudios,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':profesion',$profesion,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':domicilio',$domicilio,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':no_ext',$no_ext,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':no_int',$no_int,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':colonia',$colonia,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':cp',$codigo_postal,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':estado',$estado,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':poblacion',$poblacion,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':tel_1',$tel_uno,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':tel_2',$tel_dos,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':tel_3',$tel_tres,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':correo',$correo,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':puesto',$puesto,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':tipo',$tipo,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':tipo_usu',$tipo_usu,PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->bindParam(':usuario',$nombre_usuario,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':contrasena',$pass,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':premisas',$salt,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':sucursal',$sucursal,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':id_empresa',$id_empresa,PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->bindParam(':nss',$nss,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':cuenta',$cuenta_bancaria,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':i_bancaria',$institucion_bancaria,PDO::PARAM_STR); 
  $stmt->bindParam(':imagen',$userpic,PDO::PARAM_STR);

  $stmt->execute();

  foreach ($_SESSION['referenciascol_temp'] as $ref){
    $sql2="INSERT INTO `referencias_personales`(`identificador`, `nombre`, `apellido_p`, `apellido_m`, `parentesco`,`calle`, `no_ext`, `no_int`, `cp`, `colonia`, `estado`, `poblacion`, `telefono`) VALUES (:identificador,:nombre,:apellido_p,:apellido_m,:parentesco,:calle,:no_ext,:no_int,:cp,:colonia,:estado,:poblacion,:tel)";

    $stmt=$conexion->prepare($sql2);
    $stmt->bindParam(':identificador',$ref['nombre_usuario'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':nombre',$ref['nombre_referencia'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':apellido_p',$ref['apellido_p_referencia'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':apellido_m',$ref['apellido_m_referencia'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':parentesco',$ref['parentesco'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':calle',$ref['domicilio_r'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':no_ext',$ref['no_ext_r'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':no_int',$ref['no_int_r'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':cp',$ref['codigo_postal_ref'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':colonia',$ref['colonia_ref'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':estado',$ref['estado_ref_guardar'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':poblacion',$ref['poblacion_ref'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':tel',$ref['tel_ref'],PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $stmt->execute();
  } 

  $conexion->commit();

  $respuesta = '1'; //Actualizacion Exitosa
  $mensaje ='';

  $stmt=null;//cierra la conexion

}catch(PDOException $error){
  $respuesta = '0';  //fallo actualizacion
  $mensaje= $error->getMessage();
  $conexion->rollBack();
}
```

Comment: Ryu, si la respuesta de @jerdguez fue tu solución, sería bueno que la marques como `aceptada`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es posible que una de las tablas sea MyISAM y otra InnoDB, esto no es es posible en la misma transacción con replicación GTID.

Si antes funcionaba y dejó de funcionar, es posible que habilitaran la replicación en modo GTID o cambiaron el motor de una de las tablas.

Comment: muchas gracias me sacaste de un problema ya llevava dos dias sin encontrar solucion enserio gracias

Comment: Ryu, si la respuesta de @jerdguez fue tu solución, sería bueno que la marques como `aceptada`.